# C++ : Storing weight for larger Graph

Tags: c++, graph, shortest-path

I was solving some question on graph. It requires to store weight for N Nodes(N<=50000). I cant use matrix to store weight of graph(as 50000x50000 can't be allocated). Do you know any other way? Thanks.

Comment: 250M numbers isn't *that* big. ... How do you try allocating? How sparse is the matrix?

Comment: Edges should be less than 100000. So i say matrix is not dense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred way of storing not too dense graphs is using adjacency lists.
The downside using adjacency lists is however that you can't directly check if node *i* is connected to node *j*. Instead you traverse all neighbors of node *i* (in which *j* would eventually show up if it is connected with node i). Also it's not practical to remove edges. I use it when doing breadth-first or depth-first searches on a graph, since one is only interested in the set of neighbors and not whether two specific nodes are connected.

In summary:

1. Takes only as much memory as you have edges (which is what you wanted) but at least as much memory as you have nodes.
2. Easy to traverse egdes for any node, i.e. *always* constant time per neighbor
3. To check whether two nodes *i* and *j* are connected you need to traverse the whole neighborhoodlist of node *i* or *j*. Which is bad if one node is connected to almost all other nodes and cheap if its connected to a few
4. Removing edges is also expensive for large neighborhoods (at worst linear time in the number of neighbors of a node) and cheap for small neighborhoods.
5. Inserting edges is very cheap (constant time)

To give you an example (first with all weights 1)

```
using Graph = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
```

now you can create a graph with *n* nodes with:

```
Graph mygraph(n);
```

And if you want to connect node *i* and *j* just do

```
mygraph[i].push_back(j);
mygraph[j].push_back(i);
```

And to traverse all edges of some node, you can simply do

```
for (int neighbor : mygraph[i]) {
    std::cout << i << " is connected with " << neighbor << std::endl;
}
```

And now for the harder problem with general weights:

```
using Graph = std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, double>>>;
Graph myWeightedgraph(n);
```

Now you can insert edges very easily

```
double weight = 123.32424;
myWeightedgraph[i].push_back({j, w});
myWeightedgraph[j].push_back({i, w});
```

And for traversal:

```
for (auto& neighbor : myWeightedgraph[i]) {
    std::cout << i << " is connected with " << neighbor.first << " with weight " << neighbor.second << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If two nodes can't have multiple edges between them:

First think of some system how to give each existing edge an unique number.
Eg. for N nodes and node numbers netween 0 and N-1, a edge between node A and node B could simply have `A*N+B` (eg. in an `uint64_t` variable)

Then make a `std::map` of edges, with the calculated number as key and the weight as value. Most operations there have logarithmic time, which is not as good than the 2D array but still good, and you need much less memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways to represent graphs. As you stated, the first one is to use an adjacency matrix. The pros are that you can easily see if two nodes `i` and `j` are connected. The downside is the space complexity (*O(V²)* where *V* is the number of vertices).

The other one is the adjacency list: for each vertex, you store an adjacency list that contains every edge coming out of that vertex. Obviously, the spatial complexity is *O(V + E)* where *V* is the number of vertices and *E* the number of edges.

Note that you can store the edges in adjacency maps instead of lists. Let's say you give each edge a unique integer key. If your graph is sparse, an `std::unordered_map` would fit well since collisions odds will be low. This grants you on average *O(1)* lookup and insertion complexity for a given edge.

If your graph can have a huge number of edges, then just use a regular `std::map` which relies on red black trees. You'll then have a logarithmic complexity for both inserting or looking up a node.

Here is some sample code:

```
struct Edge {
    int weight;
    int start, end;
}
struct Vertex {
    int key;
    std::unordered_map<int, Edge> adjacency_map;
}
struct Graph {
    std::vector<Edge> edges;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't allocate an array with size of orders 10^9 as a static memory. You should be using malloc instead. Better still, you can use [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) to store the graph.